# How to add several scalar fields in a mayavi/tvtk unstructured mesh?

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I start from the `datasets.py` example given here :
[datasets.py](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_datasets.html) where an unstructured grid has been build:

```
...
ug = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid(points=points)
ug.set_cells(cell_types, offset, cell_array)
```

and a scalar field is added:

```
scalars = random.random(points.shape[0])
ug.point_data.scalars = scalars
ug.point_data.scalars.name = 'scalars'
```

My question is : how can I add several scalar fields to the same unstructuredGrid object? I know the datastructure of `vtk` can handle this but I can't figure out how to proceed with the tvtk interface.

I think the question would hold for any other kind of dataset (StructuredGrid, PolyData, ...)

Comment: Can you point to a corresponding vtk example of what you're looking for?

Comment: If you have a look on the vtk file format documentation [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiRrZuEg-7gAhXHDGMBHcWuAJQQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vtk.org%2FVTK%2Fimg%2Ffile-formats.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3SgbI6PQRAy15-tBTG2VXE), on page 7 you can see for instance that the ASCII format allows to insert as many `FIELD` as wanted.

Comment: But actually someone already found a solution in this post : [Save data to VTK using Python and tvtk with more than one vector field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035620/save-data-to-vtk-using-python-and-tvtk-with-more-than-one-vector-field)